# Firebase signInWithRedirect to go directly to specific URL

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have a 'Continue with Google' button on login.html, and post sign-in I'd like the user to immediately go to account.html. From what I understand, this is best done with the `onAuthStateChanged` method.

I have the following code on my login page, which after login sets a session variable and then redirects:

```
continueGoogleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  signInWithRedirect(auth, provider) });

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user)
      const data = {
        data_type: 'email',
        data_value: user.email
      };
      fetch('/set_session_data', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          window.location.href = "{{ url_for('account') }}";
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to set session data');
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Network error:', error);
      }); 
  }
});
```

However whilst this works, it doesn't seem right to me. Post login, the user is redirected back to login.html, and has to wait a second or so for the code to execute before they're redirected to account.html. From my user experience when using other sites, Google OAuth seems to immediately send the user to the desired page rather than route them via the original page. Am I missing something? It sounds like a pretty basic thing, to be able to go from login -> Google -> account, rather than login -> Google -> login -> account.